# macOS: Change default app for files with no extension

Tags: macos, finder

I want to change the default app for files with no extension from TextEdit to BBEdit.
Cannot seem to find a correct answer to this.
Using 'Change All' on a file's Info tab brings up an error ('not enough information available').
'defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSHandlers ...' does not work.
Spotlight and Finder search did not help.

So where is the magic marker that tells macOS to use TextEdit ?